# How to use web3-react with truffle Dapp? any sample code / tutorial?

Tags: web3js, dapps, react

I am new to react and finding issues with the front-end of the Dapp application.

Especially in web3 version > web3 1.0.0

I just heard about the web3-react and I think it will be a lot easier.

I follow the https://noahzinsmeister.gitbook.io/web3-react/ and https://github.com/katopz/web3-react-example but could not find any working example or code for the application with web3-react, truffle Dapp

Can you provide any tutorial link/video for such application?

Also, open for the suggestions as I am very new to Dapp(ethereum) and React.

Thanks.

Comment: There was a very interesant thread on Zeppelin forum about front end libraries for Ethereum https://forum.zeppelin.solutions/t/do-you-use-web3-to-frontend-libraries-like-web3-react/714.

Answer (score 0):

I developed a truffle box using react and the latest version of web3. check this link https://github.com/rouftom/truffle-react-material.